# Simple .bat keeps popping up errors

Tags: batch-file

I'm making a .bat to open some programs when I'm going to start streaming, but it says it can't find the pathways.

This is my bat:

```
taskkill /f /im Spotify.exe
taskkill /f /im Snaz.exe
taskkill /f /im obs64.exe
taskkill /f /im chrome.exe

cd /d "C:\Users\marka\AppData\Roaming\Spotify"
start C:\Users\marka\AppData\Roaming\Spotify\Spotify.exe

cd /d "F:\Stream Local\Snaz"
start F:\Stream Local\Snaz\Snaz.exe

cd /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\obs-studio\bin\64bit"
start C:\Program Files (x86)\obs-studio\bin\64bit\obs64.exe

start chrome https://www.twitch.tv/markaabo
TIMEOUT 1
start chrome https://streamlabs.com/dashboard#/
TIMEOUT 1
start chrome https://inspector.twitch.tv/#/
TIMEOUT 1
start chrome https://twitter.com/markaabo
pause
```

But when it comes to `cd /d "F:\Stream Local\Snaz"` it fails a puts out an error message says "Windows can not find F:\Stream. control that you spelled it correct, and then try again" (Sorry if its translated wrong my pc is on danish)

Comment: Have you tried putting "" around the paths in your `start` calls? (e.g. `start "F:\Stream Local\Snaz\Snaz.exe"`)

Comment: The CD command is pointless if you are using the full path to the executable to start the application. You could use the /D option with the START command as well.

Comment: @Forty3 put a title after start, too. `start "" "F:\Stream Local\Snaz\Snaz.exe"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were missing double quotes around some of your start paths

**EDIT** 
I've updated the answer to be more compact

```
start "Launch Spotify" /d "C:\Users\marka\AppData\Roaming\Spotify" "Spotify.exe"
start "Launch Snaz" /d "F:\Stream Local\Snaz" Snaz.exe"
start "Launch obs64" /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\obs-studio\bin\64bit" obs64.exe"

start chrome https://www.twitch.tv/markaabo
TIMEOUT 1
start chrome https://streamlabs.com/dashboard#/
TIMEOUT 1
start chrome https://inspector.twitch.tv/#/
TIMEOUT 1
start chrome https://twitter.com/markaabo
pause
```

Comment: Its worked so thanks, but something i notice is my cmd still sometimes come im with the error Windows can not find F:\Stream. control that you spelled it correct, and then try again" but only rare like 10 times outta 100 but if i just run it again it works